# How to implement Interface in Mainwindow

Tags: c#, wpf, interface

I'm rewriting my project, so it's easier to edit in future, and want to implement interface.

I've implemented the interface, but it doesn't work in MainWindow, I'm not able to call the method.

So I've tried to use the PalindromeChecker as the default implementation
        `PalindromeChecker = new PalindromeChecker();` , so I can call the method but it didn't work.

```
interface ICheckPalindrome
    {
        bool IsPalindrome(string text);
    }
```

```
public class PalindromeChecker : ICheckPalindrome
    {

        /// <summary>
        /// Method for checking if the word/text is a palindrome.
        /// </summary>
        public bool IsPalindrome(string text)
        {
            ......
            //Code
            }
        }
    }
```

```
  namespace TextChecker
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            lblInput.Foreground = Brushes.ForestGreen;
            lblResult.Foreground = Brushes.ForestGreen;
            lblTitel.Foreground = Brushes.ForestGreen;

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// User input and checking the input if the word a palindrome is.
        /// </summary>
        private void InputText_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            string text = InputText.Text;

            bool isPalindrome = PalindromeChecker.IsPalindrome(text);

            OutputText.Text = text + (isPalindrome ? " is a palindrome" : " is NOT a palindrome");

            if (InputText.Text == string.Empty)
            {
                OutputText.Clear();
            }
        }
        private void ButtonClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            SubWindow subWindow = new SubWindow();
            subWindow.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

```
 public class PalindromeChecker : ICheckPalindrome
    {

        /// <summary>
        /// Method for checking if the word/text is a palindrome.
        /// </summary>
        public bool IsPalindrome(string text)
        {
            int min = 0;
            int max = text.Length - 1;

            while (true)
            {
                if (min > max)
                {
                    return true;
                }

                char a = text[min];
                char b = text[max];

                if (a != b)
                {
                    return false;
                }

                min++;
                max--;
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm really stuck here, I would like to thank you in advance.

Comment: There is a problem in your logic. You cannot call a Class as a method. You should create an instance of 'PalindromeChecker' and then call the method using that instance.

Comment: @Lupu Silviu Without interface this code line ``bool isPalindrome = TextChecker.PalindromeChecker(text);``works.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are using Interfaces to implement that method? If not, discard the interface, and make the method 'IsPalindrome', public static bool.

Comment: I need to make an Interface, so if "customer" wants smth new I dont need to rewrite whole code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as can see, you don't want *interfaces*, class *instances* to check for a palindrome (do you really want to implement *several algorithms* to choose from?), but a `static` method:

```
    // Let's class be partial one: if you want to add a method it it
    // you don't have to modify this code but 
    // add a chunk public partial static class MyStringRoutine {...}
    public partial static class MyStringRoutine {
      public static bool IsPalindrome(string text) {
        //DONE: do not forget about special cases
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
          return true;

        for (int i = 0; i < text.Length / 2; ++i)
          if (text[i] != text[text.Length - 1 - i])
            return false;

        return true;
      }
    }
```

Then you can use it:

```
    private void InputText_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e) {
      if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(InputText.Text)) 
        OutputText.Clear();
      else {  
        string suffix = MyStringRoutine.IsPalindrome(InputText.Text) 
          ? "is a palindrome"
          : "is NOT a palindrome";

        OutputText.Text = $"{InputText.Text} {suffix}";  
      }
    }
```

If you have to implement `ICheckPalindrome` interface, and thus to work with *class instance*, you have to *create the instance*:

```
  private void InputText_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e) {
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(InputText.Text)) 
      OutputText.Clear();
    else {
      // You have to create the instance (checker)
      ICheckPalindrome checker = new PalindromeChecker(); 

      // IsPalindrome is the instance method; you can't call is as 
      // PalindromeChecker.IsPalindrome
      string suffix = checker.IsPalindrome(InputText.Text) 
        ? "is a palindrome"
        : "is NOT a palindrome";

      OutputText.Text = $"{InputText.Text} {suffix}";  
    }  
  }
```

Comment: @Bob: I doubt if `ICheckPalindrome` inteface is of any help here. It might have been helpful if we could have different algorithms/implementations with their pros and cons to choose from.

Comment: Bycheno But I need to implement it.

Comment: Thank you very much, I've tried the same way but i've tried to create the instance out of the method

Comment: @Bob: you can't create an instance of a method, but instance of a class

Comment: I ment to, create the instance above the method.

Answer (score 0):

From code you've posted it'd seem that interface `ICheckPalindrome` is less accessible than `PalindromeChecker`. Not sure how and why your compiler would let that slip, but you should try changing your code to

```cs
public interface ICheckPalindrome
{
    bool IsPalindrome(string text);
}
```

So the interface will reflect its implementation (or rather other way around).

Comment: Hi, I forgot to add I tried to set it public, but the problem remained.

Comment: Can you edit your post and add `TextChecker` class code as well?

Comment: Yes I did, the TextChecker is only the solution name, btw im using VS 2019

Comment: Are you instantiating `PalindromeChecker` anywhere? I can't find it in your code? Maybe it was `static` in your code before refactoring?

Comment: I'm not instantiating it anywhere, PalindromeChecker is only Class , I use it in MainWindow and for UnitTest to check the method.

Comment: You cannot use non-static method of a not instantiated class. This might be the cause. Try creating new instance of PalindromeChecker instead and see if it works.

Comment: Thanks, I will try , will see who it goes.